# What distros work with/for raspberry pi

Tags: linux, ubuntu, raspberry-pi-desktop

I was just wondering if literally any linux distro will work on raspberry pi for only Linux distro that are (for/made for) the raspberry pi

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: think about the CPU and memory size requirement

Comment: @jsotola By that criteria the answer is "they will all work" since memory/cpu minimums apply to specific software configurations that are themselves applicable to almost any distro -- if you want to run the SantaClaus desktop environment it may be too much for a Pi, but that is true regardless of whether you use SantaClaus on Ubuntu, Alpine, Raspbian, or NewFooWhatever.  Conversely, if you want a sans GUI install, there is no distro that could possibly have made that too resource intensive for even the wee tiniest Pi -- *if it is just about "CPU and memory size"*.